# Adobe Edge Fonts web beacon

Tags: adobe, webfonts, privacy

I tried Adobe Edge Web Font on my website and I discovered that they use a 1x1 beacon called p.gif. What's the purpose of this [web beacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon)?

---

A solution is to write *"img-src 'self' data:"* into the Header CSP. *data:* is for Safari that doesn't show audio controls otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a means of tracking your users. You can block it by using a CSP rule that doesn't include their domain for images. Use [report-uri.com](https://report-uri.com) to help you configure an appropriate CSP header.